# How to schedule multiple notification using alarm manager?

Tags: android

I'm developing an application that has a module called doctor visit appointments.
In the appointments I have multiple appointments in a day. I want to remind a appointment to the user using alarm manager, but I have array of appointments.
If I set the alarm manager with these appointments, the alarm manager will show only one notification others will cancel.

Is there any way to achieve this functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can schedule multiple alarms. Only thing that you have to ensure is each alarm should have a different id in the pending intent:

```
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
PendingIntent broadcast = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, requestCode,
                myIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

the requestCode above should be different for all alarms.

Comment: Thank You so much

Answer (score 1):

Use [JobScheduler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobScheduler):

> By introducing JobScheduler at the system level, you can focus on batching similar work requests together, which results in a noticeable improvement for both battery and memory.
>
> JobScheduler is becoming the go-to answer for performing background
> work in Android.  Android Nougat introduced several background
> optimizations, for which JobScheduler is the best practice solution.
>
> So, if you haven’t already, it’s time to jump on the JobScheduler
> train.

JobScheduler is the way to go with API if your app targets Lollipop (API level 21) and above.

For implementation, you can use [Android Job](https://github.com/evernote/android-job) and for a more detailed explanation you can look here:

1. [Scheduling jobs like a pro with JobScheduler](https://medium.com/google-developers/scheduling-jobs-like-a-pro-with-jobscheduler-286ef8510129).
2. [Easy Job Scheduling with Android-Job](https://android.jlelse.eu/easy-job-scheduling-with-android-job-4a2c020b9742)

Comment: is job scheduler trigger the notification after kill the app?

Comment: @Arigarasuthan Yes. You can try it yourself.